# which best IDEs with ROS

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am using spyder with ROS but  I would like to change another IDE.

please, your suggestions

I read more IDE [here](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#code)

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331304/which-best-ides-with-ros/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2019-08-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PapaG](https://answers.ros.org/users/40565/papag/) on 2019-08-22**:
I won't answer cause they're all the same. Pretty much, just pick what you enjoy. It is entirely personal preference. I use Visual studio code cause I can use it on all platforms and it has a terminal built in. There is also an extension for ROS to help with sourcing the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started with Eclipe but got into a lot of issues in importing a ROS package and then compiling it.

I switched to CLion afterwards and everything worked like a charm. Its really easy to just install ROS plugin in it and import a project using `CMakeList.txt`. Only problem is its free for 30 days evaluation. Afyerwards you have to buy the license.

I have heard a lot about QTCreator but did not use it. Hopefully one day.

---

Originally posted by [usamamaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40953/usamamaq/) with karma: 146 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-22**:
thank you for your suggestions, what about pycharm?

**Comment by [usamamaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40953/usamamaq/) on 2019-08-23**:
I have extensively used PyCharm for python codes. Its a great tool. Still using it. But have not used for ROS (C++) packages. For that i am using CLion.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-24**:
I am using only a python

is it great?

do you recommend me using it?

**Comment by [usamamaq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40953/usamamaq/) on 2019-08-24**:
Yes i am happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*ALL* of those IDEs on the [IDEs wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) are best for someone. Only you can determine which one is best for you.

I suggest you spend 5-10 minutes looking at each one, pick the 2 or 3 that look best for you or seem to solve the problems you have with spyder, and spend 1-2 hours trying each one.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-22**:
thank you so much for your suggestion, I will do it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I liked Visual Studio Code because of its flexibility in opening any type of file with the help of available extensions (ROS extension is also there, plus extensions for C++/CMake/XML/JSON/Python,etc). If you are using it for first time then it might take some time to get familiar. Rest you can check the IDEs wiki page suggested below.

---

Originally posted by [Prasun2712](https://answers.ros.org/users/22415/prasun2712/) with karma: 13 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-22**:
thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Previously I suggest QTCreator but now definitely will choose VS Code!

RoboWare which is developed by a Chinese company is quite popular in China but now discontinued.. which is based on VS Code also.

That's why we'd better choose an IDE which is maintained by big companies so we can keep updating..

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2019-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-22**:
Thanks, VS Code is fine??

**Comment by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on 2019-08-26**:
for me, I think it is more than enough compared to other IDEs. Eclipse is so redundant so super slow, QTCreator is fine, but VS code you can add extensions, much more flexible